# Finding a recurrence relation for $2\times N$ tiles with red and blue tiles and utmost 2 similar colored neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, tiling

this question has 1 tricky aspect I don't know how to address.

Basically We are asked to color $2\times N$ tiles with red or blue 1x1 tiles. However,
a tile can only have up to 1 similar colored tile neighboring it.
Two tiles are neighbors if one is above, below, left or right to another tile.
Meaning, diagonal tiles aren't neighbors.
The problem with the recurrence relation is that I don't know what to do in [this event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMjL.png).

If the first 2 tiles are the same color, then the rest of the tiles are already
predetermined. This happens both for when the first 2 tiles are red and where they
blue.

How do I add this option into the recurrence relation?

Comment: The easiest way is to add it in at the end.  Make a recurrence for versions that start with different colored tiles, then add $2$ for ones that start with two of the same.

Comment: @RossMillikan But I think that adding 2 to the equation causes it to multiply by 2 for every recursive action. They example I showed can't occur unless the entire tiles are colored that way. I'm trying to figure out how to add that option into the equation in a correct way

Comment: As I said, you add it in at the end after you have done the recursion.  Define $a_N$ as the number of acceptable colorings of $2 \times N$ that start with two differently colored tiles.  Find and solve the recursion for $a_N$.  Then the total number of colorings of $2 \times N$ is $a_N+2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh I see now! I thought that it may be incorrect doing it that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider any coloring of a strip of $2 \times n$. It's last pair of tiles must be red, green or green, red. The only way to extend it is to add green, red respectively red, green; i.e., one way.

As a starting point, you know there is $1$ way to color the strip of length $0$, and $2$ ways to color the strip of length $1$.